# tmap Color in legend doesn't match the actual map

Tags: colors, tmap, color-palette

I tried to draw a map using tmap with the color palette in grey scale. However, I can not get the legend to match the actual color in the map.

Here are my codes:

```
 tmap::tm_shape(ut_master_T10) +
  tmap::tm_polygons(
    col = "t2d.18_64.censusrate.per1k.q5",
    palette = c("#FFFFFF", "#DEDEDE", "#BEBEBE", "#5F5F5F", "#000000"),
    alpha = 0.7,
    lwd = 0.5,
    title = "") +
  tmap::tm_layout(
    frame = FALSE,
    legend.outside = TRUE,
    legend.hist.width = 5,
    legend.text.size = 0.5,
    fontfamily = "Verdana") +
  tmap::tm_scale_bar(
    position = c("LEFT", "BOTTOM"),
    breaks = c(0, 10, 20),
    text.size = 0.5
    ) +
  tmap::tm_compass(position = c("LEFT", "TOP"))
```

And here is the picture:

[image]

I tried using a different scale (ie viridis), and it is very clear that the color in the legend is lighter than in the actual map.

[image]
Can someone please help me?

Thank you!

Comment: How did you get the inset? If I use your code with the World data set the colors in the map are the same like in the legend (both are slightly transparent due to the use of `alpha = 0.7`).

Comment: I used the viewport() command. But even if I removed the inset, the colors in the legend are still slightly lighter than in the map.

Comment: Can you provide the data set and the shapes?

Comment: @mgrund, I figured it out. Apparently, when i used "alpha = 0.70" in tm_polygons, the transparency only applies to the legend and not the figure itself. Which is interesting also. Thank you so much for your help!